# simple copy protection strategy

Tags: validation, passwords, copy-protection

Just thought I'd run this idea past far more experienced heads.
I've made a desktop application in java 8. It is a niche app that will be sold via a single website. The market is individuals in a specific work environment who would not be "tech-savvy", and who are either on or chasing a 6-figure salary. My client, the publisher/vendor anticipates sales of maybe (don't laugh) 50-100 per year... so it's very niche. The retail price of the software, because of the low volume and niche setting, is to be around $100. So it's just a pet project that maybe helps to fund the family holiday at the end of the year.

The target customers will be on a high enough salary to not worry about paying the premium for the software (tax deduction anyway), which will directly enhance their ability to make more money, but they also have a reputation for having few scruples, and would generally not care about casually copying the software and giving it to their work mates.

The software will not be able to connect to the internet, so it's stand-alone, isolated.
So I need a copy protection scheme that is simple, not onerous to the end user and, due to it's target market and low volume, doesn't need to be "hacker-proof".

So this is what I've come up with:

- Vendor has a "password" generator, that uses a simple algorithm, an
  adaptation of the Luhn formula, that is capable of a few million
  unique 8-char strings, out of a total possible pool of a few hundred 
  billion. So a valid password would be very hard to guess. Software
  downloaded, generated password emailed to customer.
- Software checks the "password" for validity, using a checksum-related
  scheme. If valid, software is unlocked, and an invisible file is created somewhere generic on the hard drive, which flags that the software install is valid.
- A different invisible file is written to the parent folder of the
  software, which contains the provided original password. This is storage for passwords that have already been used, and are therefore invalid.
- Next time the software is launched, it checks for the existence of
  the validated-flag-file-- if it exists, then the software launches,
  otherwise it asks the user to contact the vendor for a new password.

  - Whenever a user needs to type in a new password, the software checks the "invalidated passwords" file. If the user types in the original password, the software won't launch, because it's invalidated. But the file also needs to exist in the parent folder, so it cant be deleted either.

The idea is that if a casual user copies the software either by itself, or with its parent folder the software wont work on another machine, even if they have the original password, but if they are legitimate (registered user who needs a copy for working at home etc) then they can contact the vendor for a new valid password, that will then work on the new copy.

Hope that makes sense. 
Comments, suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Full disclaimer: I work for Link Data Security and is your competitor, but this doesn't stop me from giving a few advises, as badly made protection damage the whole copy-protection community.

First of all you need to look into how hackers crack your program and try to deffend against their usual attacks. That would be debugging, changing your code when testing for validation, copy of key/validation-file and many more. This is the things I can remember from the top of my head. There will always come new cracking methods, due to hackers being very creative people.

If I was you I would try to run my program in a sandboxed enviroment, see what it does. Then make sure that files created or such doesn't help the hacker to find a good way to hack your protection.

> Next time the software is launched, it checks for the existence of the validated-flag-file-- if it exists, then the software launches, otherwise it asks the user to contact the vendor for a new password.

From your description of your program I find it worrying that copy/move of your validated-flag-file to a new computer seems to break the copy protection. Also finding invisible files is the first thing a new hacker will learn, so this is the same as no protection.

A colleague of mine wrote a tutorial on what to take into consideration when making copy-protection, maybe this will help you on your way to being a copy-protection expert: [All About Copy Protection](http://www.linkdata.com/theory.htm)